# wpf search in collection

Tags: wpf, search, collections

How do I search into my collection ??

Can't get it working... Don't I just have to do :

```
            Contacts c = new Contacts();

        if (c.Contact_name == "Test") {
            MessageBox.Show("exists!");
        }
```

Does not work :-)

```
public ObservableCollection<Contacts> contacts = new ObservableCollection<Contacts>();


    class Contacts
{
    public string Contact_id { get; set; }
    public string Contact_name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you jsut created an object why would you expect its property to have some value? Post your full code which does not work.

Comment: Your class has no property called `Contact_name`. Maybe its a typo (`Contact_grname` instead of `Contect_name`)

Comment: Yeah confusing question.. but try `if(contacts.Any(c=>c.Contact_name=="Test"))` with an actual collection that stores a `Contact`.

Comment: the values are created, is just nog in post :-)  @Lews does not work, does not contain .Any definition

Comment: @keno For all the [System.Linq.Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Linq.Enumerable.aspx) methods (Any, FirstOrDefault, etc.) you would have to write `using System.Linq;`.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting `c` to a new instance of `Contacts` which does not have the `Contact_name` property set to anything...

If you're trying to search a collection for a specific contact, the easiest way would probably be to use the following Linq statement, which will return the first object in the collecting matching your condition, or `null` if no object is found

```
contacts.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Contact_name == "Test");
```

There's other Linq extensions that may be better suited for you depending on what you want too, such as `.Exists()` if you only want to know if an item exists or not

If you're not using `Linq`, the easiest way would be with a loop

```
foreach(var c in contacts)
{
    if (c.Contact_name == "Test") {
        MessageBox.Show("exists!");
    }
}
```

Comment: @keno You'll have to post more of your code for us to be able to help you then. What you have now is code that initializes a new `Contact` object, and a new `ObservableCollection` that is meant to hold `Contact` objects (which is empty by default). I do not see where your contact objects are created at all.